# Stateful Widget not rebuilding after BLOC state change

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble to understend why my Stateful widget is not updating the state after a rebuild. I have a stateful widget responsable for decrementing a counter each second, so it recieves a initial value, I pass this initial value to the State and start decrementing it.

Also it has a button that when pressed sends a event to my bloc which rebuilds the stateful widget with a new initial value, the thing is, it indeed sends and update the initial value, but the counter continue decrementing the old value and I have no clue why. Here a example of the code:

Widget

```dart
void main() => runApp(
      BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => TBloc(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: BlocBuilder<TBloc, BState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is BState) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Counter(state.value),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text("tap"),
                        onPressed: () =>
                            BlocProvider.of<TBloc>(context).add(BEvent(200)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                return Container();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialValue;

  Counter(this.initialValue);

  @override
  CounterState createState() => CounterState(this.initialValue);
}

class CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  Timer timer;
  int value;

  CounterState(this.value);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() => --value);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text("Value: $value"),
        Text("Initial: ${widget.initialValue}")
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Bloc

```dart
class TBloc extends Bloc<BEvent, BState> {
  @override
  BState get initialState => BState(100);

  @override
  Stream<BState> mapEventToState(BEvent event) async* {
    yield BState(event.value);
  }
}

class BEvent extends Equatable {
  final int value;

  BEvent(this.value);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [value];
}

class BState extends Equatable {
  final int value;

  BState(this.value);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [value];
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you are only setting your `Timer` on your `Counter`'s `initState` which is called *only* once per widget lifecycle.

Basically, when your `Counter` is first built, it will call `initState()` and as long as it remains in that widget tree, only `didUpdateWidget()` and/or `didChangeDependencies()` will be called in order to update *that*  widget (eg. when rebuilt with new parameters, just like you're doing).

The same happens for `dispose()` method, which is the opposite of `initState()` called only *once* but this time, when the widget is being removed from the tree.

Also, you are using states the wrong way here. You don't need to pass the parameters to the state itself (like you are doing by:

```
 CounterState createState() => CounterState(this.initialValue);
```

but instead, you can access *all* parameters from that widget by calling: `widget.initialValue`.

So, with all of that said, basically, what you'll want to do is to update your `Counter` widget based on the new updates, like so:

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialValue;

  Counter(this.initialValue);

  @override
  CounterState createState() => CounterState();
}

class CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  Timer timer;
  int value;

  void _setTimer() {
    value = widget.initialValue;
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() => --value);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setTimer();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Counter oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if(oldWidget.initialValue != widget.initialValue) {
     _setTimer();
   }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text("Value: $value"),
        Text("Initial: ${widget.initialValue}")
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you so much! I thought that when I send the new state the BlocBuilder would remove the Widget from the tree, build a new one and add it to the tree, but I think I miss undertood it, right? If you have the time could you give me a brief explanation about what is really happening? Is it just been updated with new values? Thank you again

Comment: Here you have a nice explanation of widget's lifecycle: https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/